# Como verificar se um elemento tem uma class, ou está com uma class "ativa"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Usei o `.toggleClass()` em uma `div`, que após clicado em um botão, ativa a class "`menu-active`", se clicado de novo, ele remove-a. Até aí tudo certo.

Só que agora para além disso, preciso de algo para verificar se essa class está ativa, se estiver, queria deixar a tag `body` do tema com um "`overflow:hidden`", se não "`overflow:auto`".

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso podes utilizar o método [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) do jQuery da seguinte maneira:

```
if ($(".menu").hasClass("menu-active")) {
    // Faz algo aqui
}
```

Eis um exemplo abaixo:

```js
if ($(".menu").hasClass("menu-active")) {
    $(".menu-active").css('color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu menu-active">Se o elemento ".menu" tiver a class "menu-active", muda o texto para vermelho.</div>
<div class="menu">Se não tiver, não faz nada.</div>
```

Comment: Não entendo muito de js, mas dei uma olhada no google, e no meu caso acho que o .hasClass() não funciona. Por que como eu disse, eu usei o .toggleClass() na minha div, e precisava que verificasse se a classe estivesse ativa acompanhando o "adicionar/remover" do toggleClass, entende? Pois bem, pelo que vi o hasClass não funciona pra isso.

Comment: @Ericki não sei o que exatamente você pesquisou, mas toggleClass é equivalente ao addClass e removeClass no jQuery. Portanto, o hasClass deve funcionar, ele simplesmente vai verificar se o elemento possui ou não uma determinada classe.

Comment: @Ericki, com certeza o `.hasClass()` vai servir no seu caso, talvez tenha ficado confuso para você por conta de ser necessário mais um seletor para utiliza-lo, e como você não postou nenhum conteúdo do seu `html`, nosso amigo sugeriu algo que fosse mais lógico...mas basicamente você teria que adicionar a classe `menu` na sua div e trabalhar a `menu-active` como já tem feito, e o seu if com o `.hasClass` vai funcionar perfeitamente...

Answer (score 1):

Com javascript é possível obter as classes usando [element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/className), onde é retornado uma string com as classes do elemento, e verificar a existência de alguma com indexOf.

```
  var classes = document.getElementById('div1').className;
  if (classes.indexOf('menu-active') !== -1){} // diferente de -1 é encontrado
```